# Kivy : line color in canvas won't update

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, kivy

I have some trouble setting the color of a line in canvas.

[image: kivy drawable app]

I have linked the color of a rectangle Line in a canvas to a property and weirdly, it does not seem to update properly. Normally the rectangle should either be red or not visible at all but it is always white here.

Here is my example kv file :

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Drawable>:
    rectangleColor: 1,0,0,1 if self.visible else 0,0,0,0
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.rectangleColor
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+0.25*self.width, self.y+0.25*self.height, 0.5*self.width, 0.5*self.height
```

And here is the corresponding python file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Kivy raw imports
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
        BooleanProperty, ListProperty

class Drawable(Widget):
    visible = BooleanProperty(False)
    rectangleColor = ListProperty([])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("touch down")
            self.visible = True
            return True
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("touch up\n")
        self.visible = False
        return super().on_touch_up(touch)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from kivy.app import App
    class drawableApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return Drawable()
    drawableApp().run()
```

Do you have any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis.

```
<Drawable>:
    rectangleColor: (1,0,0,1) if self.visible else (0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks, root did not change anything but the parenthesis did !

Comment: As soon as the edit is validated, I will validate the answer. Thanks @kiok46

Comment: Yes seen, and validated, root did not change anything since root and self are the same here but anyway that's also corrected

Comment: Yeah! Right `root` and `self` are same here, I am happy to help :)